# Close postgres transaction - Elixir

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

I am trying raw sql query with Elixir,

Postgres connection opens and transaction successful

But after that, query transaction is not closing, it remains in Idle state.

```
qry = "select id from table where id = 1"
{:ok, pid} =  Postgrex.start_link(
                hostname: "localhost",
                username: "user",
                password: "password",
                database: "db",
                pool_size: 100)

Postgrex.query!(pid, qry, [])
```

In Postgres,

```
PID     Query  status
2323    qry     Idle
```

How to close the transaction after completing the execution.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ please respect those reading the questions from not-so-wide screens, format lines accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

So, [`Postgrex.query!/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/postgrex/Postgrex.html#query!/4) runs an extended query. You can close an extended query with [`Postgrex.close!/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/postgrex/Postgrex.html#close!/3), but looks like only in this way:

```
{:ok, conn} = Postgrex.start_link([])
query = Postgrex.prepare!(conn, :query_name, "SELECT * ....")
result = Postgrex.query!(conn, query, [])
Postgrex.close!(conn, query)
```

Comment: function Postgrex.close/1 is undefined or private

Comment: result = Postgrex.query!(conn, query, [])   =>  throws argument error
_ (ArgumentError) argument error  :erlang.iolist_to_binary(%Postgrex.Query{column ... _